# Scipy's parameterization of Generalized Gamma vs wikipedia's

Tags: distributions, survival, gamma-distribution, scipy

[Wikipedia's parameterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution) of the Generalized Gamma distributions pdf is relatively straightforward

$$
f(t; a,d,p) = \frac{p/a^d}{\Gamma(d/p)} t^{d-1} e^{-(t/a)^p}
$$

[Scipy's parameterization](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats/continuous_gengamma.html) of the pdf is
$$
f(t; a,c) = \frac{|c| t^{ca - 1}}{\Gamma(a)} e^{-t^c}
$$

Im having trouble understanding where Scipy's parameterization came from. I attempted to prove the two were equivalent with algebra but I ended up with some leftover terms. **How does the math work out and how do the parameters of each relate to eachother between the 2 parameterizations?**

Attempt below

$$
f(t; a,c) = f(t; z,c) = \frac{|c| t^{cz - 1}}{\Gamma(z)} e^{-t^c}\\
\frac{|c| t^{cz - 1}}{\Gamma(z)} e^{-t^c} = \frac{p/a^d}{\Gamma(d/p)} t^{d-1} e^{-(t/a)^p}\\
\text{guess substitution:}\:\: z = d/p\\
\frac{|c| t^{c(d/p) - 1}}{\Gamma(d/p)} e^{-t^c} = \frac{p/a^d}{\Gamma(d/p)} t^{d-1} e^{-(t/a)^p}\\
 = |c| t^{c(d/p) - 1} e^{-t^c} = p/a^d t^{d-1} e^{-(t/a)^p}\\
\text{guess substitution:}\:\: c = p\\
|(p)| t^{(p)(d/p) - 1} e^{-t^p} = p/a^d t^{d-1} e^{-(t/a)^p}\\
 = t^{d - 1} e^{-t^p} = p/a^d t^{d-1} e^{-(t/a)^p}\\
 = e^{-t^p} = p/a^d e^{-(t/a)^p}\\
$$

and this last line is where I've gotten stuck.

Comment: Related paper: Crooks, "The Amoroso Distribution", https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.3274v2

Comment: @JDoe I suggest you use a different variable for the two densities; they are on different scales and you will want to find the relationship between the corresponding random variables.

Comment: Scipy does not include the scale parameter $a.$  Therefore, you may set $a=1$ in the first formula before comparing them. There's little left to observe, because you can easily match parameters by comparing the forms of the two formulas.  For instance, the "$\Gamma(a)$" in the second formula must coincide with the "$\Gamma(d/p)$" in the first formula and the power $t^c$ (within the argument of $\exp$ in the second formula) must coincide with the power $t^p$ present in the first formula.

Comment: @JDoe `scipy` uses the convention that all scale parameters are omitted from the definition of the PDF/CDF and instead exposed via the `scale` parameter in the methods, for instance `pdf(x, a, c, loc=0, scale=1)`. This fact is crucial to understanding how to compare scipy methods with other resources like Wikipedia.